# passing data between activity not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass some data from one activity to a new one but every time I push a listed item it shows the passed intent but doesn't pass the info. The toast pop up shows the right data that I'm trying to show before the new activity.

Can anyone please help.

TimsList.java

```
public class TimsList extends ListActivity {
int ct_id;
String[] ct_number = null;
String[] ct_address = null;
String[] ct_phone = null;
String[] ct_fax = null;
String[] ct_email = null;
String[] ct_city = null;
String[] ct_province = null;
String[] ct_country = null;
String[] ct_pcode = null;
String[] ct_long = null;
String[] ct_lat = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.bob.com/app_main_list.php");
        //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    //paring data

    JSONArray jArray;
    try{
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;
        ct_number=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_address=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_phone=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_fax=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_email=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_city=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_province=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_country=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_pcode=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_long=new String[jArray.length()];
        ct_lat=new String[jArray.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ct_id=json_data.getInt("location_id");
            ct_number[i]=json_data.getString("store_number");
            ct_address[i]=json_data.getString("store_address");
            ct_phone[i]=json_data.getString("store_phone");
            ct_fax[i]=json_data.getString("store_fax");
            ct_email[i]=json_data.getString("store_email");
            ct_city[i]=json_data.getString("store_city");
            ct_province[i]=json_data.getString("store_province");
            ct_country[i]=json_data.getString("store_country");
            ct_pcode[i]=json_data.getString("store_pcode");
            ct_long[i]=json_data.getString("store_long");
            ct_lat[i]=json_data.getString("store_lat");
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Addresses Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    setListAdapter(new
            ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ct_address));
    ListView lv;
    lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> timslist, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ct_phone[position]+" was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimsListMore.class);
            //i.putExtra("ct_id_pass", "ct_id");
            //i.putExtra("ct_number_pass", "ct_number");
            //i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", "ct_address");
            i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", "ct_phone");
            //i.putExtra("ct_fax_pass", "ct_fax");
            //i.putExtra("ct_email_pass", "ct_email");
            //i.putExtra("ct_city_pass", "ct_city");
            //i.putExtra("ct_province_pass", "ct_province");
            //i.putExtra("ct_country_pass", "ct_country");
            //i.putExtra("ct_pcode_pass", "ct_pcode");
            //i.putExtra("ct_long_pass", "ct_long");
            //i.putExtra("ct_lat_pass", "ct_lat");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    }
 }
```

TimsListMore.java

```
public class TimsListMore extends Activity {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timslistmore);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        String string1 = b.getString("ct_phone_pass");
        //String string2 = b.getString("ct_id_pass");

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); 
        tv1.setText("" + string1 + "");
 }
```

}

Comment: You are adding String in extras : i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", "ct_phone");..It is not displaying "ct_phone" ?..Check whether the Bundle Object in TimsListMore class is null or not and display result in Toast.

Comment: TimsListMore.java does show ct_phone but i need the value not the text.

Comment: Try this i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", ct_phone); instead of i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", "ct_phone"); ..

And in TimsListMore Activity, --> String[] my_ct_phone= b.getStringArray("ct_phone_pass");

Comment: i did i1.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", ct_phone[position]); and it worked!

Comment: ok good one..I thought you want to pass whole array of strings ..

Comment: no we need to pass some here some there but all comes from the DB so this will work, but thx for the help.

Comment: mark this post as solved by posting the solution. As it was solved by you only, post your answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by changing

```
i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", "ct_phone");
```

to

```
i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", ct_phone[position]);
```